# JavaFX Scene Builder: How to uncheck "Resize" option in Layout tab?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, scenebuilder

I want to make my .fxml application to not be resizeable, but I am not able to uncheck "Resizeable" check box on any anchorPanes, the option is greyed out. The same thing happens even on a new, completely empty project.

[image]

```
Product Version
JavaFX Scene Builder 1.1

Build Information
Version: 1.1-b35, Changeset: 50e3d7cdf394
Date: 2013-08-27 10:45
```

Answer (score 18):

For resize functionality,you need to have stage of main class. initial stage reference will use it for make it non -resizable.

Try this.

**MainClass.java**

```
public class MainClass extends Application {

public static Stage stage;
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        this.stage = stage; // initialize value of stage.
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

**SampleController**

```
 MainClass.stage.setResizable(false);
```

Comment: In what method within the controller would you put `MainClass.stage.setResizable(false);`? Thanks.

Comment: Inserting it within MainClass.java after `stage.show()` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In **Main.java** add:
**`primaryStage.setResizable(false);`**
before the:
*`primaryStage.show();`*